Little spikes on mains AC
I live in an apartment complex. From time to time I would hear a buzzing on my UPS. At first I thought it was defective but then, when I disconnected it and plugged my PC directly to the outlet, the buzzing would move to the PC PSU, just it was a little bit quieter.
At one point I decided to unplug everything and just put the power strip close to my ear and again, I could hear that buzzing, this time much quieter.
Pulled my oscilloscope and found these little spikes when that buzzing was happening, they look to be ~2000Hz when I measured.
My questions are:

Am I right to assume that the noise from the UPS was due to the size of the electronic components? It is a line interactive 2400VA UPS with pure sine output.
What could cause this? When I measured it, my UPS, PC and fridge were disconnected.
Can I somehow filter these spikes for my apartment or at the very least, close to my PC?



Is it by any chance exactly 120 degrees out of phase as in 3.33 ms out from zero crossing? If you have tankless water heater with zero crossing on another phase and this leaks over via neutral. Or just phase control somewhere on same phase as in vir’s answer.

For more information, take the FFT of the signal and note the amplitude of the harmonics of the line frequency.

@winny The position of the spikes is suspicious, personally I don't have a water heater but the building has 12 apartments, maybe a neighbor has it.

@user71659 I will see if I can buy a bench-top oscilloscope in the next days, the one that I have although it shows the fft (the red lines) it is impossible to see what they mean.

Looks like another load is using phase control. This is a way to adjust how much average power a load consumes by waiting until a certain point in the cycle before turning it on - that's where you're seeing the transients. The load doesn't have to be on your specific circuit, just another unit in the apartment building on the same phase (possibly a portable/window AC unit?). The transients could probably be filtered out with an inline module from a reputable manufacturer (do not buy some $10 "spike buster" off of Amazon).

I never considered ACs, my building has 12 apartments and it is hot lately, that could explain it. Is there a brand/model that you can recommend for the filter?

@AlexandreBorela Asking for products or where to buy them is off-topic here -- we're mainly concerned with engineering and design topics. Thus, identifying the waveform, possible causes, effects, and solutions (e.g. circuitry) is in scope, but I'm afraid a packaged solution is not.

The usual suspect where I live is a tankless water heater. It is both powerful enough to generate the electrical noise and has almost no other means to regulate its power vs the flow rate in order to maintain the required temperature.

@AlexandreBorela your UPS seems to be doing a pretty good job of filtering already.  I think you are specifically looking for a filter that won't buzz, and you won't be able to determine that without trying them :(

@MattTimmermans not necessarily a very good job. This is a line-interactive UPS with an iron transformer, most of these in their normal state just use the transformer in reverse to power the internals and charge the battery. This is why the buzz happens. The input power is directly connected to the output and no filtering happens in between.

Interesting @fraxinus, that's more sophisticated than we tend to have here. Whole house tankless is  gas so tankless electric is at point-of-use.  There might be a couple of power settings, but the temperature regulation is by flow regulation.

@ChrisH I see. We don't have gas, but we do have 230/400v 3-phase as a norm, so whole house tankless electric is normal as well.

vir's answer covers the basics, I just want to put some additional information here.
What you're hearing, is most likely electrostriction: the change in dimension (strain) of a solid when subjected to an electric field.  Namely, the capacitors in the mains input filter of the UPS or PC.  A quiet buzzing noise is not unusual from these components.  This effect (or the analogous magnetostriction in inductors) is also what gives rise to the whining or clicking sound from lightly-loaded or idling power supplies (which pulse on briefly once in a while, at an audible repeat rate).
What is unusual is the waveform.  It seems unlikely you'll be able to address the source, but a line filter could indeed be used.  Judging from the risetime and ringing of the transients, an ordinary one might not do much: frequencies below 150kHz aren't much of a concern for radio emissions and thus filtering.  You would need one with a fairly low cutoff frequency, 10kHz or below by the looks of it.  You also need one that's designed in such a way to not emit sound (by the same mechanism) itself..!
On the upside, it's highly unlikely to be a functional or lifetime problem for connected equipment; just the nuisance of the audible buzzing.
